# What is "Healthy (OEM Partition)" and can it be removed?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

This is on a Win 10 Pro 64-bit laptop.

In the attached screenshot you can see that I have three small partitions called "Healthy (EFI System/OEM Partition)".

It's been quite a while since I've been in Disk Management, but the last time I was, I'm quite sure those weren't there. I recently started a Windows reinstallation a couple of times but stopped it before I was committed to the operation, so I'm wondering if those were created as a result of that. Just a guess...

[image]

Comment: This [link](https://www.minitool.com/partition-disk/strange-partitions-on-laptops.html) explains the different partition types. Unless you embarked on a factory reset, the OEM partitions would not have appeared from nowhere. Oddly, the main EFI partition is empty, so you must be booting with the LRS_ESP partition (unless you have configured legacy boot). The OEM partitions usually contain drivers and utilities used during recovery for the specific hardware, though they look unusually small for this.

Comment: The OEM partition is your recovery partition, it usually stores windows created by manufacturer. And I think you need a recovery partition. If you remove the OEM partition, and when you want to restore the machine, you could be able to only restore it to be the original.

Answer (score 1):

OEM partition is used for recovery purpose when your system fails to boot up. When you insert your recovery disk it will fetch recovery points from this OEM partition and try to restore to the previous restoration points which will be mentioned in this partition.

You can surely delete this partition without facing any issues. If you manually want to create such partition again then you can do it by booting with Windows Bootable disk.

Reference: https://www.urtech.ca/2018/12/everything-you-need-to-know-about-healthy-oem-partitions-and-how-to-easily-remove-them/